# ASP.NET: Is it possible to create dynamically-named Javascript functions without using .NET code (ie, VB.NET or C#)?

Tags: asp.net, function, dynamic

I have a custom user control (ascx) that contains a textbox and a Javascript-based counter to let the user know many characters they have left to type.  In this control is the following:

```
function GetTextBox() {
    return document.getElementById("<%=txNotes.ClientID %>");
}
```

This worked fine when we only had one instance of this user control on the page, but now we have to support multiple.  As you know, having multiple instances of this control on a page will result in multiple GetTextBox() functions, only the last of which will be called no matter what.  To support multiple instances, I use this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBoxName) && !Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(TextBoxName))
{
    string Script = string.Format("function Get{0}Notes() {{ return document.getElementById(\"{1}\"); }}", 
        TextBoxName, txNotes.ClientID);

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), TextBoxName, Script, true);
}
```

`TextBoxName` is a public usercontrol property, so if the developer passes Employee through, it will generate a Javascript function called `GetEmployeeNotes()`.  This works greate because now we can have a unique GetNotes() function.

However, I don't like how it's hardcoded into the codebehind.  I would like a markup-based solution for this, something that doesn't require a rebuild of the project in case I want to change the Javascript.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

**Edit**: I've already thought of creating a separate .js file that I could read with a text reader, but that sounds a bit hacky and I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

**Edit 2**: Guard's answer below would work, but I don't want to go that route for the reason I gave beneath his answer.  If no one can offer another way to do what I want to do, I will most likely mark his as the answer since it technically does exactly what I am asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a .NET specialist, but isn't it working as a preprocessor?

Isn't it legal to write

```
function Get<%=Name %>Notes() {...}
```

?

Comment: This works, but it "breaks" the IDE. For example, you know how the IDE will snap code into place as you finish an expression with a `;` or `}`? Having that kind of server tag in the middle of everything makes the IDE think something is syntactically incorrect, so it stops auto-formatting your code until you "fix" it.

Comment: It is for this reason that, when I need to carry an int or long to the markup from the codebehind, I do this:
`var n = parseFloat("<%= EmployeeId%>");`

Comment: OK, great, then do window["Some<%= Name%>"] = function () {}

Comment: I can't do this because this function will be called from the parent's page's Javascript and I would need to know the ID which is dynamically generated based on its control hierarchy. If I were using .NET 4.0, I could do this, but I am at 3.5.  Besides, I just tried this Javascript in FF and it doesn't appear to work.  Works in IE, though.

Comment: that's really strange. you should be able to do `name = "Some<%= Name%>"` in _any_ part of the page, as well as `window[name] = function (params) {}` (function declaration) and `window[name](params)` (function call)

Comment: > and I would need to know the ID which is dynamically generated based on its control hierarchy


Well, but that's what you request, isn't it - you want the function to have unique name based on your control name. What I suggest in the comment is _exactly_ the same written win the post, but with a different sugar to make your IDE a bit happier

Comment: As I posted in another answer, I don't want to hack it by forcing a name or id into the element via Javascript.  Am I annoying yet? Edit: In my question, I already stated that yours is most likely going to get marked as the answer if no one else can come up with another idea.

Comment: Sorry, I don't realize what's the problem and what you expect. You want the function name to be unique and include the control ID? If yes, than you have to go this way. If no, then I don't actually understand how your ideal solution could look - could you pleae give some ideal pseudo-code that you would like having at the end of the day?

Comment: I need to be able to dynamically generate a Javascript function.  It had nothing to do with the ID.  The ID is something other people were bringing up.  I am just going to mark yours as the answer like I said I would.  I don't think there's a way to register a function dynamically using client-side code the same way I have done it in the codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a generic function and just pass the id of the corresponding textbox? As in: GetNotes(thisTextBoxId) {...}. Not only would that deal with your problem but also is more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: I thought of that, but this function is called from the parent page's Javascript.  I would need to know what the Id of the control is which is dynamically determined at runtime, so I'd be right back at square one.  I am using .NET 3.5, so I also can't force the Id of the textbox to what I want.  I could put a non-server DIV around the textbox and give it a dynamically-assigned Id.  This would let me go like `document.getElementById("NoteDiv").controls[0].value` (or whatever the syntax is), but that also seems hacky to me.

Comment: Since I am using .NET 3.5, I can't force an Id into the control from the codebehind.  I could hack it if I wanted and use client script to set the .id or .name property, but I want to explore other conventional options first.